# excell vba errors saving a file after importing a worksheet with a picture

Tags: vba, excel

I have written VBA code that copies an entire workbook (worksheets and code) into another.  This allows me to create a unique workbook containing only worksheets I need for a particular project.  Everything works great except when I copy a workbook which has a worksheet with a picture.  It imports OK but when I try to save the receiving file I get a message saying "Errors were detected while saving 'filename'. Microsoft Excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features....".  If I continue it says it can not repair the file.  If I delete the picture it saves just fine.  Any ideas on what is causing this and how to fix it? I tried png, jpeg, and tiff file types.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Also, what version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

For me this error happened when I pasted in a graphic straight from ms-paint.  I saved that graphic instead as .jpg and inserted it using Excel->Insert->Picture.